# How can I add eventGrid to a http trigger in Azure Functions in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-eventgrid

The goal is to write data to a topic in Azure, but I receive the following error:

> The 'PostBooking' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'eventGrid' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.

I develop this locally.

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
let booking = req.body;
var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
context.bindings.bookings = booking;

context.bindings.outputEvent = {
    id: 'message-id'+timeStamp,
    subject: 'Booking',
    dataVersion: '1.0',
    eventType: 'event-type',
    data: booking,
    eventTime: timeStamp
};
context.res = {
    status: 201,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: {
        message: booking.id
    }
}
context.done();
```

}

**function.js**

```
    {
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "bookings/"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputEvent",
      "type": "eventGrid",
      "topicEndpointUri": "{hidden}",
      "topicKeySetting": "{hidden}",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "bookings",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "out",
      "databaseName": "{hidden}",
      "collectionName": "bookings",
      "createIfNotExists": true,
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDB"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

**error message**
[image]

I don't know what to do?

Comment: Hey, please try these https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/issues/54 solutions.

Comment: I have added this one https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventgrid-extension/issues/54#issuecomment-515455305 but it didn't solved the problem. Other solutions are written in .NET.

Comment: instead of adding screenshot, could you add code? it's easy to copy-paste.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4909 found something here as well

Comment: try deleting FunctionBundles from temp folder

Comment: I've deleted FunctionBundles from temp folder but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/issues/10. The binding `eventGrid` has just been added into [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle](http://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/commit/8753d86fdb4170736df6e3d28857cdcb13022d5d)  , but the latest version has not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

I later found out that it isn't possible to add eventgrid to http trigger yet, only event grid trigger. To publish events to event grid, I have used this code. [Index.js](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/event-grid-node-publish-consume-events/blob/master/EventGridPublisher/index.js)